# Cisco Forwarding ASIC Buffer failure

Tags: cisco

We have Cisco fex Switches which connect to 5696 and we see this errors on them.

"forwarding ASIC Buffer failure"

Do you have any Experiences ?

Comment: We cannot solve hardware problems. You need to contact Cisco TAC about replacing the switch..

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

That’s hardware failure. You’ll need to open up a Cisco TAC case for them to assist and likely issue an RMA to replace the FEX.

Answer (score 3):

Likely a hardware problem, like the others have mentioned, but possibly a reboot could already help: https://community.cisco.com/t5/server-networking/nexus-2148-asic-failure/td-p/1642252 - I'd also try a full power cycle.

Comment: It happens again after reboot.

Comment: Then you should contact TAC.